# How can I implement a has_many :through association two ways?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a property model and a user model.

A user with the role of 'admin', which is represented by a column on the users table, can have many properties.

A user with a role of 'guest' can also belong to a property, which gives them access to that property.

How should I do this in Rails?

Answer (score 0):

authorizations table -> user_id, property_id

```
class Authorization < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :property
end 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :authorizations
    has_many :properties, through: :authorizations
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :authorizations
    has_many :users, through: :authorizations
end
```

then you can do `User.find(id).properties`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a [has_many :through](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association between your models `User` and `Property`. So, create a new table *properties_users* with columns *user_id* and *propety_id*. And do following changes to the models:

```
class PropertiesUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :property
end 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :properties_users
  has_many :properties, through: :properties_users
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :properties_users
  has_many :users, through: :properties_users
end
```

Now, we need to make sure that a guest user does not have more than one property. For that we can add a validation to model `PropertiesUser` like below:

```
class PropertiesUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :validate_property_count_for_guest

  private

  def validate_property_count_for_guest
    return unless user && user.guest?

    if user.properties.not(id: self.id).count >= 1
      self.errors.add(:base, 'guest user cannot have more than one properties')
    end
  end
end 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def guest?
    # return `true` if user is guest
  end
end
```

Finally, to access a guest user's property, define a dedicated method in model `User`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def property
    # Raise error if `property` is called on non-guest users
    raise 'user has multiple properties' unless guest?

    properties.first
  end
end
```

Now, you can fetch a guest user's property by running:

```
user = User.first

user.guest?
 => true

user.property
 => <#Property 1>    # A record of Property
```